# how to dynamically update HTML5 canvas via server push without page reload?

Tags: html, canvas, push

What I would like to do is create a canvas that will show a network map.  It's not really a network map but in terms of explaining it the network map example works best to not bog you down with details that don't pertain to my question.

On the network map I want to display routes the traffic takes.  These routes change in time, sometimes as frequently as multiple times per minute.  On the server side I have a log file to which each route change is appended as it happens.

I know how to create the canvas, I know how to draw my routes onto the canvas.

Is it possible to have the server push an update to the canvas without requiring a page reload/refresh, essentially requiring no user interaction at all?  The routes drawn just automagically change?

This would need to work on IIS so a jscript or .Net based solution would be necessary.  I won't be able to install PHP, Python, Ruby etc.

Thanks in advance for any insights you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you look at a WebSockets solution to push the information from the server to the client (JavaScript). When you receive the update you can update the canvas as required.

Technologies you should look at if your preferred server technology is .NET would be a service like [Pusher](http://pusher.com), who I work for, and our [.NET APIs](http://pusher.com/docs/rest_libraries#cs) which let you push updates to the client via our REST API.

If you would prefer to host your own realtime infrastructure then you could look at [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com) (which is actually a Comet technology) which integrates with IIS and also [XSockets](http://xsockets.net). There are also a number of realtime technologies on [this guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide) which may interest you. If you've any further questions just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Server-Sent Events: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics

( Server-sent events is a technology for providing push notifications from a server to a browser client in the form of DOM events. The Server-Sent Events EventSource API is now being standardized as part of HTML5[1] by the W3C. )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've done this before (with an ajax-based drawing application). It's very possible. Send packets of information via AJAX (JSON or something), interpret them, and draw them on the client's canvas element. This is trivial to design (and easy to implement using something like jQuery). It seems that you already figured out you need to have a server-side script that pushes information to a web page and a web page that actually draws stuff on the canvas. That's essentially all it is.

Comment: I suppose you did answer the question of whether it is possible.  My bad for asking an overly simplistic question.  Any chance you would have a link to an example?  Googling for it results in information overload without actually getting to the bottom of it.  No doubt a function of search terms used.